# Undertow always add charset to Content-Type header even if it is not a text MIME type

Tags: java, servlets, wildfly, undertow, wildfly-10

If I try to set the content type to "image/jpg" in a servlet

```
response.setContentType("image/jpg")
```

I get

```
Content-Type: image/jpg;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

The default servlet works well instead.

How can I get rid of charset for non text mime types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used resp.getWriter() instead of resp.getOutputStream() to serve images.